# Recall same setInterval after clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an `<iframe>` which is changing its content dynamically and I want to access the elements of `<iframe>`

Somehow I got access to the elements inside `<iframe>` using `$("#myIFrame").contents().find(".iframeElement").on("click", function(){...}`

Now issue is I only got access to static elements of `<iframe>`, and for accessing dynamic elements I used `setInterval` which recall the above jquery function every second. That gives me multiple duplicate callbacks. So I tried `clearInterval` that stops it completely.

Then I also tried calling above `setInterval` and `clearInterval (if previous already exists)` inside another `setInterval` which is also giving me multiple duplicate callbacks! Due to orphan `setIntervals`

**So is there a well-structured way to call same `setInterval` after `clearInterval`**

Hope you're getting my point!